# woocommerce Dragonpay payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

how and where dragonpay access to my site/plugin so that dragonpay can update of order status in woocommerce?this is the callback method in my plugin

```
class payment_gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
  function callback(){
     global $woocommerce;
     $order_id = $_GET['txnid'];
     $status = $_GET['status'];
     $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
     if ($status == 'S') {
         $order->add_order_note('Dragonpay Payment Status: SUCCESSFUL');                             
         $order->payment_complete();
         wp_redirect($order->get_checkout_order_received_url());
         exit;
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: Through it's own extended method `payment_complete()` normally… You should see in it the `update_status()` `WC_Order` method.

Comment: $order->payment_complete() is to update order status to complete..then where i should set the post back of the dragonpay

Comment: Not necessarily, it can be also processing… `payment_complete()` is used for "successful" payments so `if ($_GET['status'] == 'S')`.